# What is the maven way to work with local forks?

Tags: java, spring, maven, git-fork

I have a java spring webapp, WebappA, that uses LibraryY.  LibraryY uses another library, LibraryZ.

Both LibraryY and LibraryZ are OSS with forkable github repos.

I want to change something in LibraryZ in way that my change could be pushed back to the origin repo.

What is the happy path to doing this using maven and github?  What is the maven way?

I git cloned Y and Z to my machine, and I ran mvn install in each.  They each built, and jars were produced, and it was fine, but WebappA depends on RELEASE builds, so me making *-SNAPSHOT builds in ~/.m2/[...] did nothing.  I think?  Which is fine.

How am I supposed to alter the source code to LibraryZ so that WebappA uses it locally?

I tried changing the version number of LibraryZ to "*-mybuild", but then it itself didn't build, because its submodules, which have no dependencies, declare LibrayZ as its parent, and their "parent" is referenced by version number?  I think?

A colleague suggested changing the groupId of LibraryZ, but I haven't tried that since that seems even crazier than changing all the version numbers in all these pom files.

It looks like the happy path is altering dozens of pom files with a change of the version number, but that seems crazy and wrong.

I feel like I am missing something, because that does not seem right.

What is the maven way of making changes to a local fork of a java library that is used by my app?

Thanks!

-neil

Comment: what about GitHub, is there available a 'development' branch of the project with SNAPSHOT dependencies?

Comment: Good question, but I am asking about the maven idiom.  Should I expect one?

Comment: Can you please explain the exact errors when you build library Z with snapshot and some other version?
And definitely changing groupId is not the solution(Even if it works, It should not be used)

Comment: Normally whenever we fork a project , we upgrade the version (major , minor) by appending SNAPSHOT as suffix.

Comment: I don't see why there are 4 votes to close this question as being too broad. The problem description is clear, and the issue is of general interest.

Answer (score 3):

There are two rather separate aspects to your problem:

1. How to make sure that your app A and library Y use your forked version of Z.
2. How to avoid confusion between your fork and official versions of Z.

Regarding 1., assuming that your starting point is a *released* version of Z, say 1.5.0, you would fork the master or trunk branch of Z which is likely to be at the next snaphot version anyway, say 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT.

If you want to start from exactly the 1.5.0 baseline, including nothing but your own modifications and excluding any other recent changes from Z master, then you'd start a branch from the 1.5.0 tag and you'd have to update the Maven versions to 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT (or whatever-you-like-SNAPSHOT). You can use `mvn versions:set` to do so.

Use the `<dependencyManagement>` section of A's POM to set the version of Z to 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT. This will override the version of Z referenced by Y.

This will be enough to test your changes. You can then submit a patch or pull request to Z and hope that your change will be included in their next release. If that is the case, then simply upgrade Z's version in your `dependencyManagement`to 1.5.1 (or whatever the next official version is).

If the Z project does not accept your changes, or if you need to release A before they are done with the next release, then you need to deal with aspect 2.

So far, you had your own local 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT which was different from official Z snapshots, which was ok, as Maven snapshots are volatile anyway.

However, your A release cannot depend on a Z snapshot, and all releases (including Z's) are immutable, so you should **not** simply build a local release of your Z fork and call it 1.5.1, because that would differ from the official Z 1.5.1 release which may happen next week, or maybe never.

In this case, it is common practice (e.g. in WildFly/JBoss Community projects) to keep the offical `groupId` and `artifactId` but to use a version with a suffix like `1.5.0-foo-1`, where `foo` is some identifier relating to your project or organization.

Should you discover bugs in your fork, you could do follow-up releases `1.5.0-foo-2`, `1.5.0-foo-3`, etc.